# How to Extend Controller Class in HMVC Module in Codeigniter to allow for Routing

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, routes, hmvc

### Question:

**How do I extend a controller of an HMVC module and then call that extended class in Codeigniter's URI Router?**

### Details:

Assuming the following typical Codeigniter file structure as it relates to HMVC:

```
/
/application
/application/modules
/application/modules/module-name
/application/modules/module-name/controllers
/application/modules/module-name/controllers/controller-name.php
/application/modules/module-name/models
/application/modules/module-name/models/model-name.php
/application/modules/module-name/views
/application/modules/module-name/views/view-name.php
/application/config
/application/config/routes.php
```

I have a class `Events` stored in `/application/modules/events/controllers/events.php`.  I would like to extend it to `Courses` and `Conferences` which would provide specific functionality to those respective controllers.  I would like to store those controllers in the same module folder (ie. `/applications/modules/events/controllers/courses.php`, etc.)  I would like to route users that visit http://www.example.com/courses to the `courses` controller like so:

```
$route['courses'] = 'courses/getList';
```

I would also like to route users that visit http://www.example.com/conferences to the `conferences` controller like so:

```
$route['conferences'] = 'conferences/getList';
```

### The Problem:

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this working because courses isn't contained in it's own module and therefore can't be found by the router.  It appears that the router is looking for the `course` class file at the following file path: `/applications/modules/courses/controllers/courses.php`. I have tried move that file to the aforementioned path, but I am then asked for the location of the `Events` controller class that `Courses` extends from.

### A Possible Solution:

One possible solution might be to contain each of the controllers in a single controller file.  However, I do not wish to do this because I like to store each class in it's own individual file and grouped with it's extended classes if at all possible.  I am looking for a more elegant and altogether correct solution.  Even if I were to attempt this technique of a single file, it would need to be contained in `/applications/modules/courses/controllers/courses.php` to be accessed.  This leaves me out of luck when trying to later route to the `conferences` controller.

Comment: The question in your title doesn't quite match the one in the post body. Is your problem with extending a PHP class (controller) or with routing? Where is the routes.php file with `$route['courses']`, in your module directory or app/config? What does your file structure look like? It's hard to visualize your problem, and I'm not sure what this "Events" class has to do with anything. What do you mean "This leaves me out of luck for the conferences controller."?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thanks for your input.  I have updated the title and question to better explain the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: Look into this [Extending HMVC modules in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15127865/782535).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by adding

```
require APPPATH."modules/events/controllers/events.php";
```

to the beginning of my extended classes (`courses` and `conferences`) I will be able to leave the `Events` module alone.

Unfortunately, I have to create separate modules for the `courses` and `conferences` controllers.  Oh well, I guess it can't be perfect.