# Extending HMVC modules in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance, module, hmvc

Let's say we have module called `core_crud` with something like this in the controller:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Core_crud extends MX_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mdl_core_crud');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // code goes here
    }

}
```

And now I want to extend this module with another module called `shop_crud`. How would the basic controller for this `shop_crud` module look like? I mean I want to inherit all the controller methods from `core_crud` and all the model stuff too.

Comment: Anybody? This should have be done somehow ;(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Structure of the Modules

```
/modules
    /core_crud
        /controllers
            /core_crud.php
        /models
        /views
    /shop_curd
        /controllers
            /shop_crud.php
        /models
        /views
```

Code in `core_crud.php`

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Core_crud extends MX_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mdl_core_crud');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // code goes here
    }

    public function mymethod($param1 = '', $param2 = '')
    {
        return 'Hello, I am called with paramaters' . $param1 . ' and ' . $param2;
    }

}
```

Code in `shop_crud.php`

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Shop_crud extends MX_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('mdl_shop_curd');
    }

    public function testmethod()
    {
        // output directly
        $this->load->controller('core_crud/mymethod', array('hello', 'world'));

        // capture the output in variables
        $myvar = $this->load->controller('core_crud/mymethod', array('hello', 'world'), TRUE);
    }

}
```

So instead of extending the whole module/controller I prefer just to call the method which is required. It is simple and easy too.

**Note** If module name and controller name are different then you have to pass the path

`module_name/controller_name/mymethod`

**EDIT to support EXTENDS**

File structure

[image: File Structure]

The code in `core_crud.php`.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Core_crud extends MX_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('core_crud/mdl_core_crud');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return 'index';
    }

    public function check_method($param1 = '')
    {
        return 'I am from controller core_crud. ' . $this->mdl_core_crud->hello_model() . ' Param is ' . $param1;
    }

}
```

The code in `mdl_core_crud.php`

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class mdl_core_crud extends CI_Model
{

    public function hello_model()
    {
        return 'I am from model mdl_core_crud.';
    }

}
```

The code in `shop_crud.php`.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once APPPATH . '/modules/core_crud/controllers/core_crud.php';

class Shop_crud extends Core_crud
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo parent::check_method('Working.');
    }

}
```

> Output :- I am from controller core_crud. I am from model
>   mdl_core_crud. Param is Working.

Hope this helps. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have already all stuff from core_crud controller and model in the shop_crud . I guess it needs to be loaded before class Shop_crud extends MX_Controller. Any idea?

Comment: Wow, thanks I will try it. One question though. Can it be nested e.g. 3 or4 levels like: **car-module** extends **vehicle-module** and **mercedes-module** extends **car-module** ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the models in the parent class or in the construct then it should be inherited in shop_crud. are you not looking to do `class Shop_crud extends Core_crud {`? is parent::__construct() not retaining the construct for you?

Is this something you can handle with routing to the same controller rather than extending a controller (wanting to inherit both the controller and the model seems strange to me or something you could handle with a route and a private function in the class to handle the logic)?

Answer (score 1):

"Controllers" this name defines it's functionality. The controller is used to control a particular section. So in MVC framework I think it's better to create individual controller for individual module. But you can reuse the model i.e. you can call one model's function in another model. For this

```
First load your model like $this->load->model("modelName"); in your controller

Then call the function like $this->modelname->functionName();
```

Comment: I am using HMVC instead of classic MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you have to require the parent controller that you are extending.  This isn't exactly ideal, but I'll look into a better way to do this later on. For now, I've created a simple function to do the inclusion.

```
function extend_module($module) {

$path = realpath(APPPATH) . '/modules/'. $module.'/controllers/'.ucfirst($module).'.php';

require_once($path);

}
```

### Usage:

```
extend_module('some_module');

class othe_ module extends some_module {
```

NOTE: The function needs to be available outside of the CI object, so put it somewhere like your main index.php file.

Also note: As these variables are used to reference the local file system, do not dynamically assign them directly from user generated input. Doing so would cause multiple file system vulnerabilities.

Platform: CI3 + Bonfire 8 HMVC